# rails dynamic route with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have the following routes:

```
Brand.all.each do |brand|
  get "/#{brand.slug}", to: 'brands#index'#
end
```

That generates:

```
"/tommy"
"/lacoste"
"/gap"
```

But when I access /lacoste for example, the page has a pagination (kaminari or will-paginate).
The pagination links are generated like this:

```
"/tommy?page=2
```

The paginate method always shows the first brand route generated.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach

Add this route at the end of the `routes.rb`.

```
get "/:slug", to: 'brands#index'
```

And you can then find the brand based on the `params[:slug]` value.

```
def index
  @brand = Brand.find_by(name: params[:slug])
  # extra code 
end
```

Comment: I can''t use /:slug because there are other routes like: /outlet, /home and so on

Comment: that's why I recommended you to move it to the bottom so only if /outlet and /home is not matched it will go to /:slug

Comment: You can also limit what you want to accept in the values using regex